# be informed when Mouse Dragging Frame

Tags: frames, mouse

When a *mouse* *drags* a maximized *frame*, that *frame* will become a normal size (i.e., not maximized).

It seems that Emacs will receive a message when its *frame* is being *dragged* by a *mouse*.

I want to run a set of functions when a *mouse* starts *dragging* (mouse starts moving after its left button is down) the *frame*

and another set of functions when the mouse-1 button is released after *dragging*.

Is there any relevant hook?

If not, how to implement that?

---

Here's a similar thing: [16.1 How Programs Do Loading](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/How-Programs-Do-Loading.html#index-load_002din_002dprogress):

> Variable: **`load-in-progress`** 
> This variable is non-`nil` if Emacs is in the process of loading a file, and it is `nil` otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any relevant hook?

Yes, it is `move-frame-functions`.

> Functions run after a *frame* was moved.